# Getting PAM-compatible password hashes from pgcrypto

Tags: postgresql, pgcrypto

I want to keep user records in Postgres database and faced one issue which block me. It is password encryption. For example, this is correcetly encrypted password `12345` via default Ubuntu `crypt` function:

`$6$P5jfk4Ufh33f$.Dc8H9jsWAl/igt4QPbYI/El28SyUEAoJPPHsLIGMKOymhC7AIaiizlW5W9hm7kU7PYMCySEhYtMqVPFsVTMK/`

As I understand first `6` means that it is encrypted via `sha384` (or `sha256`) algorithm. Ok, i created an extension `pgcrypto` in desired database, but following code: `SELECT digest('12345', 'sha384') as pwhash;` returns absolutely different result - without algorithm mark and salt:

 `\x0fa76955abfa9dafd83facca8343a92aa09497f98101086611b0bfa95dbc0dcc661d62e9568a5a032ba81960f3e55d4a`

I want to get exactly specified format because it is used by PAM to check user credetials and it does not understand password hashed another way.

Comment: You will probably have to format the value yourself, using the underlying crypto functions. In this case it looks like a base64-encoded hash, so you can base64-encode the bytea result from `digest`, then prepend the algorithm identifier and the salt that PAM expects. The format PAM requires will be documented.

Comment: @CraigRinger unfortunately it is quite bad solution (but for now it looks like only one) because `gen_salt` operates only with `bf/md5/xdes/des` and cannot works with `sha256/512`.